# PySpark Dataframe: Remove rows by dates

Tags: sql, dataframe, date, pyspark

I'd like to reduce my spark dataframe to dates after a certain date e.g., 2020-03-01.

Loading the data via sql gives me a string for the data column, so I changed it before trying to remove rows via data comparison.

Unfortunately, my approach below results in an empty df.

```
query = "select id, date , volume from "+ INPUT_DB + "." + INPUT_TABLE
sdf_monthly = spark.sql(query)
sdf_monthly.count()
>>>113683937

sdf_monthly=sdf_monthly.withColumn("date", F.to_date(F.unix_timestamp(sdf_monthly["date"],"YYYY-MM-DD").cast("timestamp")))
sdf_monthly_new =sdf_monthly.filter(sdf_monthly["date"] >= F.unix_timestamp(F.lit('2020-03-01')).cast('timestamp'))
sdf_monthly_new.count()
>>>0
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you are comparing a date with a linux timestamp. Try:

```
sdf_monthly_new =sdf_monthly.filter(sdf_monthly["date"] >= F.to_date(F.unix_timestamp(F.lit('2020-03-01')).cast('timestamp')))
sdf_monthly_new.count()
```

Comment: Thanks, good point - but unfortunately gives the same result.

Comment: Can you validate that you actually have data after filtering ? 
You can try filtering with SQL
`query = "select id, date , volume from "+ INPUT_DB + "." + INPUT_TABLE + "WHERE date > ='2020-03-01'"`

Comment: Yes I started with that but that also gave me an empty dataframe. I assumed it is since the date column comes as string. Another solution I tried was to define date as Datetype within the sql query but that leads also to an empty df. 
`"select id, cast(to_dat(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date_as_of))) as date) , volume from "+ INPUT_DB + "." + INPUT_TABLE + "WHERE date_as_of > ='2020-03-01'"`
But the reason is not that there is no data with date >= 2020-03-01 that is for sure.

Comment: what database are you using (MySQL,SQLServer,Oracle,Postgres, etc) .Can you update the question with the DDL of the table (the CREATE TABLE statement) and some sample data ? 3-4 rows owrth of data

Comment: one way to test if you have data is to order your dataframe and check the first row.

`sdf_monthly_new =sdf_monthly.orderBy('date', ascending=False)` 

`sdf_monthly_new.first()`